# Does a conservative form of the Chew-Goldberger-Low MHD equations exist?

Tags: energy-conservation, magnetohydrodynamics

I wonder if is it possible to bring Chew-Goldberger-Low MHD equations to a conservative form? Conservative form of the system of equations of ideal MHD with isotropic pressure is well known and can be found in many textbooks. What is the analog of the plasma energy in the Chew-Goldberger-Low MHD? Note that this theory is also called double-adiabatic approximation.

I guess that conservative form of the CGL MHD equations exist, but where it is published?

Comment: Do you have a link to a resource about these CGL MHD eqns? I've never heard of them, though I'm fairly well familiar with the ideal MHD eqns (and some of the non-ideal forms).

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: See original paper by Chew, G. F., Goldberger, M. L. & Low, F. E. 1956 Proc. Roy. Soc. A. 236, 112 or adaptation by Kulsrud: http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~hassam/761/notes/Kulsrud-Mhd_Description_of_Plasma.pdf

Comment: Looking at Chew et al (1956), it appears to be what's done in Goedbloed & Poedt's MHD Vol I book (taking moments of the Boltzmann/Vaslov eq'n); but I've sold my copy so I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: @KyleKanos - CGL MHD is basically just MHD but allowing for anisotropic pressure tensors, where there is one parallel (with respect to $\mathbf{B}_{o}$) and two equal perpendicular pressure components (i.e., $P_{\perp,1} = P_{\perp,2}$).

Comment: @Igor - Is there anything in CGL MHD that says it's not conservative?  Can't you just assume infinite conductivity and still use CGL or do you need some finite resistivity?

Comment: @Igor - Just to clarify, what do you mean by _plasma energy_ in your question?

Comment: @honeste_vivere: If partial time derivative of something is equated to a divergency of some flux, they say that the equation is written in a conservative form. In Kulsrud's papers, I found that energy of plasma in MHD is $W=\rho V^2/2+p_{\bot}+p_{\|}/2+B^2/(8\pi)$ but an expression for $\vec{S}$ in the equation $\partial_t W=-\textrm{div}\vec{S}$ is given only for isotropic plasmas, And yes, CGL MHD assumes infinite electric conductivity.

Comment: @Igor - Your first comment is just a statement of a continuity equation.  Your expression $W$ is the total pressure in the system, which is (unit-wise) an energy density.  The last part is just the dissipationless version of Poynting's theorem.  With infinite conductivity, there can be no magnetic field diffusion and the electric field only exists in reference frames not moving with the bulk flow...

Comment: @honeste_vivere: please read a textbook before further flooding, e.g. MHD instabilities (Cambridge, Mass., MIT Press, 1978.) by G.Bateman, section 2.3.

Comment: It seemds that answer to my question can be found here: http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/pofb/5/11/10.1063/1.860581